# Is $\{t\mapsto \cos(at) \}_{a\in \mathbb{R}^+}$ linearly independent of $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: vector-spaces

We consider the family  $F=\{t\mapsto \cos(at) \}_{a\in \mathbb{R}^+}$ of functions of space $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.
Is $F$   linearly independent of $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

I know that $\{t\mapsto \cos(at) \}_{a\in \mathbb{R}^+_*}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$. But I have no idea about $F$.
An idea please.

Comment: @Marktmeister But $a>0$

Comment: I misread the question, hence I deleted my comment. So the difference between $\mathbb R^+$ and $\mathbb R^+_*$ is that the former contains $0$?

Comment: @Marktmeister yes

Comment: Are you allowed to use derivatives? If $\lambda_0 \cdot 1 + \lambda_1 \cos(a_1 t) + ... + \lambda_n \cos(a_n t) = 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$ and distinct $a_1, ..., a_n > 0$, then derive twice with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am spelling out the approach I mentioned in the comments.

Let $a_1, ..., a_n \in \mathbb R^+_*$ be distinct. Since you've already shown that $\{t \mapsto \cos(a_j t) \ | \ j = 1,..., n\}$ is linearly independent, suppose that $\lambda_0, ..., \lambda_n$ are real numbers such that

$$\lambda_0 \cdot 1 + \lambda_1 \cos(a_1 t) + ... + \lambda_n \cos(a_n t) = 0 \text{ for all } t \in \mathbb R.$$

In other words, the function $g \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by

$$t \mapsto \lambda_0 \cdot 1 + \lambda_1 \cos(a_1 t) + ... + \lambda_n \cos(a_n t)$$

is the zero function. This function is differentiable twice with

$$g''(t) = -a_1^2\lambda_1 \cos(a_1t) - ... - a_n^2 \lambda_n \cos(a_n t) = 0.$$

As you've already shown, the condition that $g''(t) = 0$ implies that

$$-a_1^2 \lambda_1 = ... = -a_n^2 \lambda_n = 0,$$

hence $\lambda_1 = ... = \lambda_n = 0$. We obtain $\lambda_0 = 0$, too.